# UPDATE Parent's UI depending upon click on child UI in fxml, java fx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am creating an application like sqlyog using javafx. My problem is that I want to add database. whenever it add,  it should update the treeView having all other databases. The dialogue of create db appears and after giving name and setting other variables, it let the user to add database. How to get the hold of this treeView ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

SQLTab.java
//class having treeview which contains treeitems of databases name along their details in tree i.e. table names,triggers, stored procedure etc.

```
package smartsql.connection.sqleditor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import static smartsql.SmartSQL.appContext;
import smartsql.connection.ConnectionDO;
import smartsql.leftpane.CreateDB.CreateDBController;

/**
 *
 * @author manoj
 */
public class SQLTab extends Tab {

    ObservableList<String> lstDatabase;
    public TreeView databaseView = new TreeView();

    public SQLTab(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        try {
            System.out.println("inside sqlTAb constructor");
            ObservableList<String> lstDatabase = SQLEditorDAO.getDatabaseDetails(jdbcTemplate);
            System.out.println("inside treeviewww");
            this.lstDatabase = lstDatabase;
            ConnectionDO  cdo = appContext.getBean(ConnectionDO.class);

            TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>(cdo.getUsername()+"@"+cdo.getHost());

            databaseView.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/smartsql/css/SQLTab.css").toExternalForm());
            for (String itemString : lstDatabase) {
                System.out.println("addingggg:::" + itemString);
                TreeItem<String> database = new TreeItem<String>(itemString);
                root.getChildren().add(database);
                ObservableList<String> lstTables = SQLEditorDAO.getTableDetails(jdbcTemplate, itemString);
                TreeItem<String> table = new TreeItem<String>("Tables");
                for (String tableName : lstTables) {
                    table.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(tableName));
                }
                database.getChildren().add(table);

                //adding for stored procedures
                ObservableList<String> lstStoredProcedures = SQLEditorDAO.getStoredProcedureDetails(jdbcTemplate,itemString);
                TreeItem<String> storedProcedures = new TreeItem<String>("Stored Procedures");
                for (String procedureName : lstStoredProcedures) {
                    storedProcedures.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(procedureName));
                }
                database.getChildren().add(storedProcedures);


                //adding for triggers
                ObservableList<String> lstTriggers = SQLEditorDAO.getTriggersDetails(jdbcTemplate,itemString);
                TreeItem<String> triggers = new TreeItem<String>("Triggers");
                for (String triggerName : lstStoredProcedures) {
                    storedProcedures.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(triggerName));
                }
                database.getChildren().add(triggers);


                //adding for triggers
                ObservableList<String> lstEvents = SQLEditorDAO.getEventsDetails(jdbcTemplate,itemString);
                TreeItem<String> events = new TreeItem<String>("Events");
                for (String eventName : lstStoredProcedures) {
                    storedProcedures.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(eventName));
                }
                database.getChildren().add(events);

            }
            databaseView.setRoot(root);

            databaseView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
                @Override
                public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
                    return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
                }
            });
            setContent(databaseView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String>{
        private ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();
        private TextField textField;
        public TextFieldTreeCellImpl() {

        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            // if the item is not empty and is a root...
            if (!empty && getTreeItem().getParent() == null) {
                MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Create Database");
                // addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
                addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
                    public void handle(Event t) {
                        System.out.print( "item text is : "+getText());
                        if(getText().contains("@")){
                            //TreeItem newEmployee =
//                        new TreeItem<String>("Create Database");
//                            getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);

                            try {
                                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/smartsql/leftpane/CreateDB/CreateDB.fxml"));
                                Parent node =fxmlLoader.load();
                                Stage stage = new Stage();
                                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                                stage.setTitle("Create Database");
                                stage.setScene(new Scene(node));
                                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                                stage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
                                stage.show();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(SQLTab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
                //   CreateDBController a= appContext.getBean(CreateDBController.class);
//                Update u = appContext.getBean(Update.class);
//                if(u.name!=null)
//                         System.out.print("newly added name: "+u.name);
                        addMenu.getItems().clear();
                        new TreeItem<String>();
//                            getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);
                        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
                        setContextMenu(addMenu);
            }

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    if (
                            !getTreeItem().isLeaf()&&getTreeItem().getParent()!= null
                            ){
                        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Create Database1");
                        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
                        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
                            public void handle(Event t) {
                                System.out.print( "item text is : "+getText());
                                if(getText().contains("@")){
                                    TreeItem newEmployee =
                                            new TreeItem<String>("Create Database");
                                    getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);

                                    try {
                                        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/smartsql/leftpane/CreateDB/CreateDB.fxml"));
                                        Parent node =fxmlLoader.load();

                                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                                        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                                        stage.setTitle("Create Database");
                                        stage.setScene(new Scene(node));
                                        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                                        stage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
                                        stage.show();
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(SQLTab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        });
                        addMenu.getItems().clear();
                        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
                        setContextMenu(addMenu);
                    }
                    if (
                            getTreeItem().isLeaf()&&getTreeItem().getParent()!= null
                            ){
                        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Create Database2");
                        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
                        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
                            public void handle(Event t) {
                                System.out.print( "item text is : "+getText());
                                if(getText().contains("@")){
                                    TreeItem newEmployee =
                                            new TreeItem<String>("Create Database");
                                    getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);
                                    try {
                                        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/smartsql/leftpane/CreateDB/CreateDB.fxml"));
                                        Parent node =fxmlLoader.load();

                                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                                        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                                        stage.setTitle("Create Database");
                                        stage.setScene(new Scene(node));
                                        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                                        stage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
                                        stage.show();
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(SQLTab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        });

                        addMenu.getItems().clear();
                        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
                        setContextMenu(addMenu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

CreateDB.fxml which is getting database name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="smartsql.leftpane.CreateDB.CreateDBController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@createdb.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
        <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="500.0"  >
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="120.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="128.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Label text="Database Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1"  >
                </Label>

                <Label text="Database Charset" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
                <Label text="Database Collation" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
                <TextField fx:id="txtDatabaseName" promptText="Database Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                </TextField>
                <ChoiceBox fx:id="txtCharset" prefWidth="500.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                </ChoiceBox> 
                <ChoiceBox fx:id="txtCollation" prefWidth="500.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                </ChoiceBox>
                <Button fx:id="createDatabase" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNewDatabase" text="Create" prefWidth="70.0" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="1"   />
                <Button fx:id="cancel" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCancel" prefWidth="70.0" text="Cancel" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4"  />

            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

CreateDBController.java

```
package smartsql.leftpane.CreateDB;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import static smartsql.SmartSQL.appContext;
import smartsql.connection.ConnectionDO;
import smartsql.connection.MySQLConnectionController;
import smartsql.connection.MySQLConnectionManager;
import smartsql.connection.sqleditor.SQLEditor;
import smartsql.connection.sqleditor.SQLEditorDAO;
import smartsql.connection.sqleditor.SQLTab;
import smartsql.connection.sqleditor.Update;

public class CreateDBController extends MySQLConnectionController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    @FXML
            ChoiceBox txtCharset;
    @FXML
            ChoiceBox txtCollation;
    @FXML
            TextField txtDatabaseName;
    @FXML

            Button createDatabase;
    @FXML

            Button cancel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        ConnectionDO  cdo = appContext.getBean(ConnectionDO.class);
        Update update = appContext.getBean(Update.class);
        update.bindName(txtDatabaseName.textProperty());

        MySQLConnectionManager connManager = appContext.getBean(MySQLConnectionManager.class);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        try {
            jdbcTemplate = connManager.connect(cdo);
            ObservableList<String> charset = CreateDBDAO.getCharset(jdbcTemplate);
            txtCharset.setItems((ObservableList) charset);
            txtCharset.getItems().add("[default]");
            txtCharset.getSelectionModel().selectLast();

            ObservableList<String> collation = CreateDBDAO.getCollation(jdbcTemplate);
            txtCollation.setItems(collation);
            txtCollation.getItems().add("[default]");
            txtCollation.getSelectionModel().selectLast();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateDBController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
    @FXML
    private void handleNewDatabase(ActionEvent even) {
        Stage stage = (Stage)createDatabase.getScene().getWindow();
        ConnectionDO  cdo = appContext.getBean(ConnectionDO.class);
        MySQLConnectionManager connManager = appContext.getBean(MySQLConnectionManager.class);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        try {
            jdbcTemplate = connManager.connect(cdo);
            String dbName=txtDatabaseName.getText();
            CreateDBDAO.createDatabase(dbName,jdbcTemplate);

            stage.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleCancel() {
        Stage stage = (Stage)cancel.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
//    public String getDatabaseName(){
//        if(txtDatabaseName.getText()!=null)
//            return txtDatabaseName.getText();
//        else return  " s";
//    }
}
```

I want to update that treeView.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing any code. But typically you would retrieve the data from the dialog in the same place in the code where the dialog is actually shown; presumably you have access to the `TreeView` there. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/55c05f6a609839552585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you show the dialog containing the CreateDB.fxml (I see this three times in your code), instead of

```
stage.show();
```

do

```
stage.showAndWait() ;
CreateDBController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
Optional<String> db = controller.getDatabaseName();
db.ifPresent(dbName -> {
    // do whatever you need with dbName, e.g.
    databaseView.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(dbName));
});
```

This will block execution until the dialog is dismissed (i.e. the user presses OK or cancels). Then you get a reference to the controller and retrieve the data from it. Using an [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) gives you a convenient way to handle "no value" in the case where the user cancels.

Then in `CreateDBController` define a `databaseName` field. Set it to the value from the user in the `handleNewDatabase` method, and set it to be empty in the `handleCancel` method:

```
public class CreateDBController ... {

    private Optional<String> databaseName ;

    // ... other code as before

    @FXML
    private void handleNewDatabase(ActionEvent even) {
        Stage stage = (Stage)createDatabase.getScene().getWindow();
        ConnectionDO  cdo = appContext.getBean(ConnectionDO.class);
        MySQLConnectionManager connManager = appContext.getBean(MySQLConnectionManager.class);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        try {
            jdbcTemplate = connManager.connect(cdo);
            String dbName=txtDatabaseName.getText();
            CreateDBDAO.createDatabase(dbName,jdbcTemplate);

            databaseName = Optional.of(dbName);

            stage.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleCancel() {
        Stage stage = (Stage)cancel.getScene().getWindow();
        databaseName = Optional.empty();
        stage.close();
    }

    public Optional<String> getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName ;
    }
}
```